# DataGrid having DataGrid for a cell upto nth level in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I need to create a DataGrid to display collection of objects in WPF.
The collection comes at run-time and is different most of the times.

The properties of the object can further be a collection.So each cell should be capable of displaying a sub-DataGrid in itself, and this can extend upto nth level.

How to create such a DataGrid in WPF ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hierarchical Data Template to achieve this.

For Example  refer the below  MVVM pattern code.

Model.cs

```
public class Person
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> MyCollection {get; set;}
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class PersonModel
{
    ObservableCollection Collection {get; set;}
}
```

XAML Code(View)

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:PersonModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" >
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.MyCollection}">
                <DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=RowDetailsTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=SelectedItem.MyCollection}">                   
                </DataGrid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Hope this will help you.....

Comment: PersonModel contains Collection property of type ObservableCollection ?

Comment: I tried you solution, but it displayed sub-data-grid for only one property(of type list). There could be more than one properties that can be presented in sub-data-grid.

Comment: For more than one property with type List, the above solution won't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use datagrid control and can set its itemsource to a observable collection of data that you want to display in each row. and for each row you can also set its content template according to your need . this content template's controls's data can also be set using binding.

Comment: The data will be dynamic. Every time we could have a different object collection.

Answer (score 1):

If all the data will be dynamic, then I would say the recommended approach would be to create your DataGrid on code-behind, and populate its columns according to your necessities. There is a `DataGridTemplateColumn`[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class that I think will help you. You can assign a `DataTemplate` to this column via the `CellTemplate` property.

You can create that `DataTemplate`via XAML or code-behind. And of course that template can contain a DataGrid. You won't be able to databind the `DataGridTemplateColumn` itself, but you can databind the elements inside the `DataTemplate`.

[DataGridTemplateColumn at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

**Example**

This is a simple example of how to do it in XAML, like I said if you need dynamic datagrids then you have to do it in code-behind. I hope this helps.

[image: Example]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="TestStackoverflow.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <!--DataTemplate for Published Date column defined in Grid.Resources.  PublishDate is a property on the ItemsSource of type DateTime -->
                <DataTemplate x:Key="DateTemplate" >
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Second grid column" Binding="{Binding ''}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                        <System:String>I heard you like</System:String>
                        <System:String>datagrids so</System:String>
                        <System:String>I put a datagrid in</System:String>
                        <System:String>your data datagrid</System:String>
                        <System:String>so you can grid while you grid.</System:String>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Original Datagrid DG Column" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DateTemplate}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Original Datagrid Text Column" Binding="{Binding ''}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <System:String>String 1</System:String>
                <System:String>String 2</System:String>
                <System:String>String 3</System:String>
                <System:String>String 4</System:String>
                <System:String>String 5</System:String>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I tried the all-code approach. Didn't succeed. You have any references?

Comment: @Brij I added an example.